# launchd process using aerender exits early

Tags: launchd

I'm trying to run `aerender` (After Effects' command-line renderer) via `launchd` to render a video on a timed interval.  The command works fine in Terminal.  In `launchd` - even when I use `screen -d -m ...` - it always exits early.  Here's my setup.

Skip to bottom for things I've already tried.

**plist for `launchd`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.home.VideoGenerator</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Users/home/Developer/VideoGenerator/exec/render.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/com.home.VideoGenerator.err.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/com.home.VideoGenerator.out.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**`render.sh` script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/Applications/Adobe\ After\ Effects\ CC\ 2018/aerender -project /Users/home/Developer/VideoGenerator/resource/video.aep -comp ExportMe -output /Users/home/Developer/VideoGenerator/output/video.mov -OMtemplate Output
```

**Output:**

Here is what normal output looks like, when I run `./render.sh` from the command line:

```
aerender version 15.0.1x73
PROGRESS: Launching After Effects...
PROGRESS: ...After Effects successfully launched
PROGRESS: Adding specified comp to Render Queue
PROGRESS:  4/2/18 8:41:57 AM PDT: Starting composition ExportMe.
...
```

This is truncated.  It also outputs composition settings and render progress, always successful.  Nothing useful for this purpose.

Here's the logged output when I run it from `launchd`:

```
aerender version 15.0.1x73
PROGRESS: Launching After Effects...
PROGRESS: ...After Effects successfully launched
```

And that's it.  (In reality I'm running this in a context where I can log the exit code and it's always 0.  For this purpose I have drastically simplified the project to what you see here, and it still doesn't run).

**Things I've tried:**

- Set `KeepAlive` to `true` in the plist

  - This just relaunches the process after it exits
- Add `/dev/null` as the `StandardInPath` in the plist (as per [this post](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=29614729&sid=cd07d9624c89b90c7cdc8dd7f9a4bd20#p29614729))

  - Still exits early
- Add `-i` and `-c` to the beginning of `ProgramArguments` (from the [same post as above](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=29614729&sid=cd07d9624c89b90c7cdc8dd7f9a4bd20#p29614729))

  - Command doesn't run
- Set `AbandonProcessGroup` to `true` in the plist

  - Still exits early
- Append `&` to put the task in the background

  - Silences output
- Launch `aerender` with `screen -d -m ...`

  - Using the -L flag and checking the log, the output is the same; it stops after `aerender` launches After Effects and then exits before rendering.

Running `ps aux | grep aerender` shows over 20 processes running (probably from all the times I've executed the script), most of them `aerendercore`.  But no output, no video.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited/Updated)

According to [this thread on StudioSysAdmins](http://www.studiosysadmins.com/board/threadview/6457/), the problem I'm running into is because of `aerender`'s reliance upon the Window Manager.

> Aerender is a hack that wraps the entirely GUI based After Effects
>   application with a basic command line render interface. The AE core
>   itself still depends directly on the Window Manager.
>   ...

-*Robin Scher*

I ended up getting around this by using AppleScript (`osascript`) in the property list like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
      <string>/absolute/path/to/run.applescript</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is what `run.applescript` looks like:

```
tell app "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"
  set w to do script "/Users/home/Developer/VideoGenerator/exec/render.sh; exit 0"
  repeat
    delay 1
    if busy of w is false then exit repeat
  end repeat
  #display dialog "finished"
end tell
```

I tell `launchd` to use `osascript` to run `aerender` in the context of a Terminal window.  A little convoluted, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

As you have discovered, [aerender requires access to the Window Manager](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/321268/1860). You could try putting your job into `~/Library/LaunchAgents` which runs in the user session, or use another scheduling tool.

## launchd Alternative

If a user is logged in or even fast user switched out, you could use a tool like [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager) to run your Window Manager requiring scripts and applications.

[image: Power Manager on macOS]

I wrote Power Manager, so feel free to ask technical questions. I suggest it in this case, because what you want is possible thanks to the tool's architecture.

### per-user and Window Manager Access

Power Manager runs a per-user process called [`pmuser`](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/guide/v4/administrator/pme.agent.pmuser.html). This process allows you to run scheduled scripts and tasks as a specified user or as the **Active User** – the front most user.

Within your Power Manager event, look for the **Environment** pop-up. This controls which user environment your shell script will run in. **Active User** is the front most graphical user session and it has access to the Window Manager.

[image: Power Manager scripting within the graphical user session]

Comment: Wonderful answer, excellent looking app there! This is exactly what I needed.  I'll get back to you when I've got it up and running :)

Comment: And FYI - I should have mentioned I was indeed running it as a LaunchAgent and it still didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: If you run into problems or need help creating the event, feel free to get in touch via support@dssw.co.uk

Comment: I ended figuring out a way to use launchd after all.  I needed to run the script every 1 minute, among other changes to the spec.  I hope your tool helps others, and thanks again for the quick answer!